# How to implement Spring Data Jpa Dynamic Query and Joint inquiry

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Current project I used Spring data jpa and spring boot, most time I found it's very convinence until meet this requirement, I found hard to deal. 
That is I have Buyer Entity and Supplier Entity and the middle Entity(BuyerSupplier), if I'd like to search Buyer by phone or name or both or all, I have to supply many methods, like below:

```
if(phone!=null&&name!=null)
    List<Buyer> findByPhoneAndName(phone,name)
else if(phone!=null)
    List<Buyer> findByPhone(phone)
else if(name!=null)
    List<Buyer> findByName(name)
else
    List<Buyer> findAll()
```

Obviously, above code is very bad.And actually, my business logic is more complex,  meantime I want to search buyer belong to a special Supplier and maybe a special status buyer. Corresponding sql like below:

```
select b.* from buyer b, buyer_supplier bs
where b.id = bs.buyer_id
and bs.supplier_id = 1
and bs.stauts = 'Activated'
and b.name like '%foo%'
and b.phone like '%123%'
```

and I also want to build dynamic sql, like below:

```
select b.* from buyer b, buyer_supplier bs
where b.id = bs.buyer_id
if(name != null)
    and b.name like '%foo%'
if(phone!=null)
    and b.phone like '%123%'
if(supplierId>0)
    and b.supplier_id = 1
if(status!=null)
    and bs.stauts = 'Activated'
```

Could anyone give me some code sample or documents could teach me how to implement my above target?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you still need to write code like `if(phone!=null&&name!=null)`.But you can enscape the code,and write once.
First, you should know the `Specification<T>` that support the dynamic query well.Just paste my code below.

```
Specification<Goods> spec = new Specification<Goods>() {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Goods> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
         Predicate predicate = cb.conjunction();
                if (goodsSearch.getGoodsClassId() != -1) {
                    predicate = cb.and(predicate, cb.equal(root.get("goodsClassId"), goodsSearch.getGoodsClassId()));
                }

                return query.where(predicate).getRestriction();
            }
        };
return goodsDao.findAll(spec, pageable);
```

ok,you can use lambda instead of anonymous class.Then you can just enscape the `Specification<T>`, put the code like `if(phone!=null&&name!=null)` in it.
the sample code:

```
public Specification<T> term(String fieldName, Operator operator, Object value) {
        return new Specification<T>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
                if (value == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                Path expression = null;
                // if a.b, then use join
                if (fieldName.contains(".")) {
                    String[] names = StringUtils.split(fieldName, ".");
                    expression = root.get(names[0]);
                    for (int i = 1; i < names.length; i++) {
                        expression = expression.get(names[i]);
                    }
                } else {
                    expression = root.get(fieldName);
                }
                // the different operation
                switch (operator) {
                    case EQ:
                        return builder.equal(expression, value);
                    case NE:
                        return builder.notEqual(expression, value);
                    case LT:
                        return builder.lessThan(expression, (Comparable) value);
                    case GT:
                        return builder.greaterThan(expression, (Comparable) value);
                    case LIKE:
                        return builder.like((Expression<String>) expression, "%" + value + "%");
                    case LTE:
                        return builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(expression, (Comparable) value);
                    case GTE:
                        return builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(expression, (Comparable) value);
                    case BT:
                        List<Object> paramList = (List<Object>) value;
                        if (paramList.size() == 2) {
                            return builder.between(expression, (Comparable) paramList.get(0), (Comparable) paramList.get(1));
                        }
                    case IN:
                        return builder.in(expression).value(value);
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

I did not write the sample code `if(phone!=null&&name!=null)` in it.